# XSLT - remove last comma

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, xslt

I am generating MySQL's create table statements. My source XML looks like:

```
<table name="TabName">
  <column> ... </column> <!-- multiple columns -->
  <primary-key> ... </primary-key>
  <foreign-key> ... </foreign-key> <!-- multiple FKs -->
  <key>... </key> <!-- multiple indexes -->
</table>
```

Transformatin is done like

```
<xsl:for-each select="column"> blabla ,</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:if test="primary-key"> blabla, </xsl:if>
<xsl:for-each select="key"> blabla, </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="foreign-key"> blabla, </xsl:for-each>
```

Please notice that I append **comma** at the end of every statement. Following SQL output then looks like:

```
    CREATE TABLE`categories` (
          `CategoryID` tinyint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
          `CategoryName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
          `Description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
          `Picture` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
           PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryID`),) --here is bad column     
   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

How can I remove that comma when doing XSLT transformation? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For fixed strings that contain commas, look at the `substring-before-last` function I implemented as [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119449/removing-the-last-characters-in-an-xslt-string/1119666#1119666).

If you create the comma yourself in XSLT, just avoid creating if it would be wrong.

```
<xsl:for-each select="...">
  <!-- ... -->
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This actually worked :) But I found better solution, to append comma before every new line that I am sure exists, not after. That did the trick even better.

Comment: @Xorty you can, but you must be _really sure_ about that existence. Otherwise you still have the need of a condition.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly manage a condition inside each iteration (or template).

Normally you use XPath to check against the current position or following siblings, like:

```
position()!=last()
```

or

```
count(following-sibling::*)!=0
```

For instance:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" media-type="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="component" select="4"/>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="column|primary-key|key|foreign-key"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="column">
        <xsl:text>blabla</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="primary-key">
        <xsl:text>blabla</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on this input:

```
<table name="TabName">
  <column>a</column> <!-- multiple columns -->
  <column>b</column> <!-- multiple columns -->
  <column>c</column> <!-- multiple columns -->
  <primary-key>pk1</primary-key>
</table>
```

gets:

```
blabla,
blabla,
blabla,
blabla
```

Answer (score 0):

Mb `last()` or `position()` functions help you?

Comment: Hmm I can't see how. Can you provide some example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452563/xslt-remove-last-comma/6453148#6453148