# xslt check for alpha numeric character

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to check if a string contains only alphanumeric characters OR '.'

This is my code. But it only works if $value matches $allowed-characters exactly. I use xslt 1.0.

```
<xsl:template name="GetLastSegment">
<xsl:param name="value" />
<xsl:param name="separator" select="'.'" />
<xsl:variable name="allowed-characters">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.</xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($value, $allowed-characters)">
    <xsl:call-template name="GetLastSegment">
      <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring-after($value, $separator)" />
      <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to check if a string contains only alphanumeric characters OR '.'

That would be

```
<xsl:when test="string-length(translate($value, $allowed-characters, '')) = 0">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:when>
```

or

```
<xsl:when test="translate($value, $allowed-characters, '') = ''">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:when>
```

---

or, FWIW even

```
<xsl:when test="not(translate($value, $allowed-characters, ''))">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:when>
```

because the empty string evaluates to `false`. I consider the latter variant as "too clever" to use it in in production code, though. Unless you do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="disallowed-characters" select="translate($value, $allowed-characters, '')" />
<xsl:when test="not($disallowed-characters)">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:when>
```

---

A generic `substring-after-last` function would look like this:

```
<xsl:template name="substring-after-last">
  <xsl:param name="string1" select="''" />
  <xsl:param name="string2" select="''" />

  <xsl:if test="$string1 != '' and $string2 != ''">
    <xsl:variable name="head" select="substring-before($string1, $string2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after($string1, $string2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="found" select="contains($tail, $string2)" />
    <xsl:if test="not($found)">
      <xsl:value-of select="$tail" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$found">
      <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
        <xsl:with-param name="string1" select="$tail" />
        <xsl:with-param name="string2" select="$string2" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The opposite (`substring-before-last`) can be found in an [earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119666/18771).

Comment: They both return Error during XSLT transformation: XSLT Stylesheet (possibly) contains a recursion.

Comment: There is no recursion in my code. Check your `<xsl:call-template>`, your condition itself is wrong.

Comment: you are right. How do I perform the substring-after($value, $separator) and print the result ?

Comment: I've added a generic solution that can pull out the last segment after a separator from a string.